# RewriteRule to extract an optional time parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

can anybody help me to make the following URLs functioning:

```
localhost/v/KmV9ffyC2kA
localhost/v/KmV9ffyC2kA?t=3m2s
```

I don't really know why this RewriteRule isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)\??t=(.*)$    index.php?v=$1&t=$2 [R]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QUERY_STRING` isn't matched in `RewriteRule`. Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t=([^&]*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?v=$1&t=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```